# how to get value of input box without id and name field using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 3 input box and all the input box does not have id, name field in it. So if i enter value in it, How can i check the value of input box without id and name field using javascript

```
<form id='a' action='' >
    <input type='text' value='' />
    <input type='text' value='' />
</form>
```

This is the code in html and i want to have the value of input box using javascript. Can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a reference to them and check their `value` property.

For the luxury of supporting newer browsers...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#a input[type='text']"),
               function(input) {
                   var value = input.value;
               });
```

If you need to support the annoying browsers that still seem to linger, just write a bit more code and you're good as gold.

```
var inputs = document.getElementById("a").getElementsByTagName("input");
var i;
var length;
var value;

for (i = 0, length = inputs.length; i < length; i++) {
     // Check we have [type='text']
     if (inputs[i].type != "text") {
         continue;
     }
     value = inputs[i].value;

}
```

Comment: He want's to check textbox value not a checkbox

Comment: @Harry I must need glasses. Updated the answer.

Comment: thanks it worked for me , I changed second last line with input.value to inputs.value

Answer (score 1):

you can get values by `getElementsByTagName` and code would be like this

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
value1 = inputs[0].value;
value2 = inputs[1].value;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't actually work. You can't subscript `undefined` (well, not usually).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`elements`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-elements) property of the form object which will iterate over just the `input` elements inside the form:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  var e = a[i];
  if (e.type == 'text') {
    f(e.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inpObj = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i in inpObj){
   if(inpObj[i].type == "text"){
         alert(inpObj[i].value);
    }
}
```

This code will alert all the input textfields.

Comment: Your method of iterating is potentially dangerous, e.g. `Object.prototype.gotcha = { type: "text", value: "not an actual value" }`. This is rather rare though :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to do form validation. For form validation in HTML5, check this resource out: 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Basically, you will be able to get by with some validations just by using HTML attributes, and without using JavaScript.